# jQuery check all checkboxes works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this function on Chrome is not working second time?

```
$('.main').on('change','input[name="select_all"]',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).attr('checked',true);
   }else{
      $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

On first click it checks all, on second it unchecks all... but on third does nothing...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j2mq/)

PS. It does add and remove checked attributes, but visually it does not change.

Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$('.main').on('change','input[name="select_all"]',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) explains the difference and lists some of the cases where you should use `prop`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.main').on('change','input[name="select_all"]',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).attr('checked',true);
   }else{
  $('input[type="checkbox"]',$(this).parent().parent().parent()).attr('checked',false);
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Beware of downvoters! May be it doesn't work, tell him in what ways it fails.